# How to show list of contents on buttons?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I want to design an app in which there will be two buttons. And when we are pressing on each button one by one, it will show a list of some content.

For this, I am using the following code:

```java
this.findViewById( R.id.UpdateList ).setOnClickListener( this );
this.findViewById( R.id.SettingsList ).setOnClickListener(buttonclicked);
```

With this i am creating butttons. For on click, I am using:

```java
ArrayList<String> smsList = new ArrayList<String>();
public void onClick( View v ) {
    //My list content for first button
}

private OnClickListener buttonclicked = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick( View v ) {
        //My list content for second button
    }
    ListView settingsListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.SETTINGSList );
    settingsListView.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>( (Context) buttonclicked  , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, settingsList) );
```

but the problem is my first list is working fine but when the second button is pressed,it stopped forcefully.

**EDIT** logcat:

```
05-13 19:44:46.988: E/AndroidRuntime(6806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
05-13 19:44:46.988: E/AndroidRuntime(6806): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bitgriff.androidcalls.MainActivity$1 cannot be cast to android.content.Context 
05-13 19:44:46.988: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):atcom.bitgriff.androidcalls.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainAc??tivity.java:506) 
05-13 19:44:46.988: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):atandroid.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627) 
05-13 19:44:46.988: E/AndroidRuntime(6806):atandroid.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329) –
```

Comment: post the exception that gets put in the logcat.

Comment: So your error is in one of the onClick methods. Post the code of the second button. You propably using `this`.

Comment: i am getting the error when i am pressing the second button( this.findViewById( R.id.SettingsList ).setOnClickListener(buttonclicked); ),which is having context with BUttonClicked in array adapter..but the first button is having context with main activity(this)....so can we make two lists like first is for one button and another is for second button...?

Comment: @user2204790 in the future if you are posting stacktrace, or source code please edit your question and add the code/stacktrace and use the code format option. Do not post as a comment because it is nearly impossible to read that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are casting yout object buttonclicked (which is an OnClickListener) to a Context.

```
settingsListView.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>( (Context) buttonclicked  , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, settingsList) );
```

Use `YourActivity.this` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this:

```
settingsListView.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>( (Context) buttonclicked, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, settingsList) )
```

to this:

```
settingsListView.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, settingsList) )
```